# SQL Create column with group_id in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create a column with group_id during the SELECT statement.

As group we will take every contact_id and product_code combination till we find event = purchase. Then if there are other event with the same contact_id and product_code combination it will be assigned as another group. Also contact_id and product_code combination with no event = purchase will be an independent group.

There are more than one contact_id-product_code combination and the data is not sorted in table.

Below the table and the expected result after SELECT

```
contact_id | product_code | timestamp               | event      |
------------------------------------------------------------------
contact_1  | product_1    | 2018-11-29 11:11:00.000 |   view     |
contact_1  | product_1    | 2018-11-29 13:10:00.000 |   add      |
contact_1  | product_1    | 2018-11-30 10:20:00.000 |   purchase |
contact_1  | product_1    | 2018-12-03 10:20:00.000 |   mail     |
contact_1  | product_1    | 2018-12-03 16:00:00.000 |   purchase |
contact_2  | product_2    | 2018-12-05 19:01:00.000 |   add      |
contact_2  | product_2    | 2018-12-05 19:03:00.000 |   purchase |
contact_3  | product_3    | 2018-12-05 19:03:00.000 |   view     |
contact_4  | product_4    | 2018-11-15 19:03:00.000 |   mail     |
contact_4  | product_4    | 2018-11-15 19:03:00.000 |   purchase |
contact_5  | product_5    | 2018-11-20 19:03:00.000 |   purchase |
```

Result:

```
contact_id | product_code | timestamp               | event      | id_groups|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contact_1  | product_1    | 2018-11-29 11:11:00.000 |   view     |    1     |
contact_1  | product_1    | 2018-11-29 13:10:00.000 |   add      |    1     |
contact_1  | product_1    | 2018-11-30 10:20:00.000 |   purchase |    1     |
contact_1  | product_1    | 2018-12-03 10:20:00.000 |   mail     |    2     |
contact_1  | product_1    | 2018-12-03 16:00:00.000 |   purchase |    2     |
contact_2  | product_2    | 2018-12-05 19:01:00.000 |   add      |    3     |
contact_2  | product_2    | 2018-12-05 19:03:00.000 |   purchase |    3     |
contact_3  | product_3    | 2018-12-05 19:03:00.000 |   view     |    4     |
contact_4  | product_4    | 2018-11-15 19:03:00.000 |   mail     |    5     |
contact_4  | product_4    | 2018-11-15 19:03:00.000 |   purchase |    5     |
contact_5  | product_5    | 2018-11-20 19:03:00.000 |   purchase |    6     |
```

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a cumulative sum.  For just an assignment:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(sum(case when event = 'purchase' then 1 else 0 end) over
                    (order by contact_id, product_code, timestamp desc
                     rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                    ), 1) as grp
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4e13d1d9e6416f32d689144580bec3f4) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

I admit that I simply cannot see why the logic is useful, because the groups are being assigned first by product and then by time.  Very strange.

The following assigns the groups:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_event = 'purchase' or seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over
                (order by contact_id, product_code, timestamp) as grp
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by contact_id, product_code order by timestamp) as seqnum,
             lag(event) over (order by contact_id, product_code, timestamp) as prev_event
      from t
     ) t
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

You can use `dense_rank()` to assign the sequential numbers you want:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by _grp) as grp
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_event = 'purchase' or seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over
                      (order by contact_id, product_code, timestamp) as _grp
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by contact_id, product_code order by timestamp) as seqnum,
                   lag(event) over (order by contact_id, product_code, timestamp) as prev_event
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f232de93de521831ee4897e3662d2ea9) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: It doesn't work. This query just returns me only 1 when event=purchase.

Comment: @dapo . . . I have no idea what your comment means.  This should be returning a value on every row.

Comment: I mean it fills the columns grp with zeros and where event=purchase grp = 1. Your solution marks only the event = purchase.

Comment: @dapo . . . I see.  You want an overall numbering, not specific to each contact/product.  (Your question is clear, my understanding was off).  I've fixed it and added a working example.

Comment: Good try you are getting there but its not the result I expect. Check my result table and yours the groups is slightly different.

Comment: @dapo . . . Your groups make no sense to me, but it is an interesting problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have a correlated subquery that counts the number of purchase's rows with an earlier timestamp, and add 1.

```
select t1.*,
      (select count(*) + 1 from tablename t2
       where t2.event = 'purchase' and t2.timestamp < t1.timestamp) as id_groups
from tablename t1
```

Core ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: It fills all the id_groups column with 1.

Comment: Better but it doesn't work. It's not giving unique group id for every contact_id-product code combination. Look my result table.